# Im trying to count the number of words in my array

Tags: java, arrays

I know there are many questions similar to this, but i just cant get my head around so im posting this in hope that someone can give me some guidance and not vote it as a duplicate.

So basically... Im trying to count all the words in my array and turn it into an integer in order to output the result. So my array for the game name is what im trying to convert. Im trying to convert the games that have been stored in there to an integer in order to output the result as follows bellow....

```
PLayers name : ......
Total games: .....
Total score: .....
Total minutes played: ....
```

Below i will show you my code which i have already...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class overflow
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            String name;

            String[] game = new String[100];
            int[] score = new int[100];
            int[] min = new int[100];

            int nextLine = 0;

            System.out.println("Can you enter your name, game, achievement score, and time played in the following format as shown below:");
            System.out.println("<NAME>");
            System.out.println("<GAME> : <SCORE> : <TIMEPLAYED>");
            System.out.println("Once you have finished your input please notify the program you have finished with the command 'quit':");

            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); // initialise Scanner
            name = keyboard.nextLine(); // assign next line of input to name

            for (int index = 0; index < 100; index++)
            {
                String input = keyboard.nextLine(); // next line of input

                if (input.compareToIgnoreCase("quit") == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
                nextLine = nextLine + 1;

                String[] variables = input.split(":"); // perform split
                if (variables.length != 3)
                {
                    System.out.println("Sorry...  You've incorrectly layed out your data.");
                    System.out.println("Please try again!");
                }
                game[index] = variables[0].trim(); // first token trimmed of whitespaces
                try
                {
                    score[index] = Integer.parseInt(variables[1].trim()); // Returns an integer/parse second token as int
                    min[index] = Integer.parseInt(variables[2].trim()); // Returns and integer/parse third token as int
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Sorry... I was unable to convert that to a number.");
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Players name: " + name);
            System.out.println("-------------------------------");

            for (int index = 0; index < nextLine; index++)
            {

                System.out.println("Game: " + game[index] + " | " + "Total Score: " + score[index] + " | " + "Minutes played: " + min[index]);

            }

            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Players name: " + name);
            System.out.println("-------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Total games: " + game.length);
            System.out.println("Overall score: " + score.length);
            System.out.println("Total minutes played: " + min.length);
        }
    }
```

Below i will show the output that i am getting for the bit that is correct and then below that i will show you what output is incorrect whiohc i need the help with.

Correct: This is the first output i need.

```
Players name: Matty Cutts
-------------------------------
Game: Brink | Total Score: 213 | Minutes played: 323
Game: Fifa | Total Score: 12 | Minutes played: 21
Game: Call of Duty | Total Score: 31 | Minutes played: 13
```

Incorrect: This is where i need the above games to added together to make an integer, whihc would be 3 because there is 3 games, after that i need the all the scores to be added and then all the minutes played to be added to then be entered in the following format..

```
Players name: Matty Cutts
-------------------------------
Total games: 100
Overall score: 100
Total minutes played: 100
```

Any advice will be greatly appreciated. Thank you for reading. Happy New Year.

Comment: You need a for-loop to iterate over the arrays and output the information for each array

Comment: How would i do that?

Comment: so it outputs three for the number of games?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need three more variables, one for the total number games, score and time played.

Then, while you're looping over the arrays printing out the information, you tally the results, for example...

```
int totalGames = 0; // could be nextLine
int totalScore = 0;
int totalPlayed = 0;
for (int index = 0; index < nextLine; index++) {

    System.out.println("Game: " + game[index] + " | " + "Total Score: " + score[index] + " | " + "Minutes played: " + min[index]);
    totalGames++;
    totalScore += score[index];
    totalPlayed += min[index];

}

System.out.println("");
System.out.println("");
System.out.println("Players name: " + name);
System.out.println("-------------------------------");
System.out.println("Total games: " + totalGames);
System.out.println("Overall score: " + totalScore);
System.out.println("Total minutes played: " + totalPlayed);
```

**Updated**

> How can i check for these on the initial inputs? Numeric values in a game entry may not represent valid integer numbers..... and The input may have blank lines, i.e. return is pressed but “quit” hasn’t been typed yet

```
public class overflow
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String name;

        String[] game = new String[100];
        int[] score = new int[100];
        int[] min = new int[100];

        int nextLine = 0;

        System.out.println("Can you enter your name, game, achievement score, and time played in the following format as shown below:");
        System.out.println("<NAME>");
        System.out.println("<GAME> : <SCORE> : <TIMEPLAYED>");
        System.out.println("Once you have finished your input please notify the program you have finished with the command 'quit':");

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); // initialise Scanner
        name = keyboard.nextLine(); // assign next line of input to name

        int totalGames = 0; // could be nextLine
        int totalScore = 0;
        int totalPlayed = 0;
        int highestScore = 0;

        for (int index = 0; index < 100; index++)
        {
            String input = keyboard.nextLine(); // next line of input

            if (input.compareToIgnoreCase("quit") == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            nextLine = nextLine + 1;

            String[] variables = input.split(":"); // perform split
            if (variables.length != 3)
            {
                System.out.println("Sorry...  You've incorrectly layed out your data.");
                System.out.println("Please try again!");
            }
            game[index] = variables[0].trim(); // first token trimmed of whitespaces
            try
            {
                score[index] = Integer.parseInt(variables[1].trim()); // Returns an integer/parse second token as int
                min[index] = Integer.parseInt(variables[2].trim()); // Returns and integer/parse third token as int

                totalGames++;
                totalScore += score[index];
                totalPlayed += min[index];
                highestScore = Math.max(highestScore, score[index]);
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Sorry... I was unable to convert that to a number.");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Players name: " + name);
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");

        for (int index = 0; index < nextLine; index++) {

            System.out.println("Game: " + game[index] + " | " + "Total Score: " + score[index] + " | " + "Minutes played: " + min[index]);

        }

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Players name: " + name);
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Total games: " + totalGames);
        System.out.println("Overall score: " + totalScore);
        System.out.println("Total minutes played: " + totalPlayed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you replace your code with the loops at the end with mine?

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much. straight after i realised what i had done. Thank you so much. MadProgrammer. I love you. You are the best. Thank you so much.

Comment: If i could upvote your answer i would upvote the S*** out of it.

Comment: Glad it could help ;)

Comment: how could i get the highest high score out of it?

Comment: `highestScore = Math.max(highestScore, score[index]);` (obviously you need to declare a `int` variable called `highestScore`)

Comment: How can i check for these on the initial inputs? Numeric values in a game entry may not represent valid integer numbers..... and The input may have blank lines, i.e. return is pressed but “quit” hasn’t been typed yet

Comment: Pretty simply actually, just more the calculations to the first loop, where you populate each element in the array

Comment: How could i do that. Ive tried and ive got no where